# I'm new to HSMs, how are keys copied from one physical HSM to another?

Tags: hsm

This scenario has come up in production, where they have to copy the keys generated in one HSM into other HSMs so that all the nodes in a cluster use the same keys. So if while copying, they will have to import right? So once keys are copied will the HSM have to be restarted or can it be done with out down time. The HSM is Thales HSM. This is all the info I have.

Comment: Thales is a large company that sells multiple HSM's that can be quite different (they were made by different organizations that got acquired or merged into Thales). So saying that the HSM is a Thales HSM is not saying much.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Pras' answer -- it is highly vendor dependent.  Keys might be able to be "backed up" and "restored" -- assuming two HSMs have the same LMK (or MBK or ... vendor dependent).

Backup/Restore is different from "export wrapped" and "import wrapped key".  Now, it isn't the LMK/MBK/... that determines whether it can be done.  Now, it is probably a local configuration policy, or a key's own policy, that determines whether it can be exported wrapped.

If you are the owner/operator of the two HSMs, and you have set them up with the same LMK/MBK/..., then in theory (assuming your HSM allows it!) you should be able to backup the key on the one, and restore it to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about how they are copied. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HSM protects the keys by encrypting them with local master keys. Outside the HSM the keys are always accessed in the encrypted form under LMK

So you cant just move the encrypted keys form HSM1 to HSM2. First you need to figure out if both these HSM has same local master key

If they have same LMKs, the keys might be moved ie the keys from HSM1 can be used with HSM2.
If they have diffrent LMKs, you might have to export the keys from HSM1 into a transport key common across both the HSMs, then import them into HSM2.

Comment: So once the keys are copied will the HSM have to be restarted for the new keys to sync in or can it be used on the go without a restart?

Comment: And thank you for the detailed explanation involving the copying of keys!! Very very helpful 